# При попытке настройки конвертации .scss в .css вылезает ошибка

Tags: sass

Ошибка:

> Encoding::CompatibilityError:
>   incompatible character encodings:
>   IBM866 and UTF-8

после этого ещё вылезает сообщение

> --trace for backtrace.

Собственно, как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: несовместимые кодировки символов: ibm866 и UTF-8

Comment: Не пойму как это исправить? Почему это вообще появилось? Раньше делал на Vista никаких дополнительных настроек из-за этого делать не приходилось. На win8 появилось... из-за чего не понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Я решил проблему следующим образом: удалил скомпилированный css-файл и рекомпилировал