# Проблемы в кодировке Sublime Text 3 LibSassBuild плагин

Tags: sass, build, sublime-text-3

Я тут установил себе плагин на sublime text 3 для автоматического build в css и вот когда я сохраняю и нажимаю билд то вот такая проблема появляется:

> Encoding::CompatibilityError:
>   incompatible character encodings:
>   IBM866 and UTF-8
>
> Use --trace for backtrace.

[image]

Comment: Скорее всего у вас путь проекта содержит кириллицу . [Другое решение похожей проблемы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284671/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-scss-%D0%B2-css-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Но у меня ни одной кирилицы нету может весь комп на англ перевести ?

Comment: какая кодировка в консоли используется?

Comment: А как посмотреть ?

Comment: Примерно так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289157/set-encoding-of-file-to-utf8-with-bom-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: У меня Стоит UTF-8

Comment: файл тоже в кодировке UTF-8?

Comment: Да файли тоже UTF-8

Comment: Что можно сделать еще ?

Comment: Насчёт некорректной работы плагинов, если ничего не нагугливается, необходимо к самим [разработчикам](https://github.com/blitzrk/libsass-build-sublime/issues) попробовать обратиться.